# Trouble displaying modal view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to call a modal view programmatically however when i click on the view to launch the 2nd view nothing happens. I also included an NSLog to see if it anything was fired. Here is my code

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //NSLog(@"Tapped");
    UIStoryboard * sb = [self storyboard];
    PredictedTimeViewController * pvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"predictedTime"];
    pvc.routeNumber = self.routeNumber;
    pvc.stopId = self.stopId;
    [self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: try changing the method to: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
and see if that helps. The method you're using is only highlighting the cell, not clicking it

Comment: I tried changing the method to:-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath still did not work.

Comment: well are you using a storyboard for the presenting of the view controller?

Comment: yes i am using a storyboard and i did give it an identifier

Comment: Does this method get called when you tap on the cell?

Comment: I added the NSlog to check if it gets called, but no it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `delegate` of the `UITableView` for the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (or `didHighlightRowAtIndexPath` as you have in the question) method
to be called. I would use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

i.e.

in the `viewDidLoad` method of the current `ViewController`

`self.myTableView.delegate = self;` // self.myTableView if it is a property

Comment: i tried that but i got an exception error: located "Hqc-GW-J82-view-7NA-UX-U5g" nib but didn't get a UITableView

Comment: How have you added the TableView to the nib? Who is the nibs View Controller?

Comment: I got it to work thanks a lot i had to change the uiview from a uitableview controller to a uiviewcontroller and set the delegate.

Comment: Good to hear @TroyBarrios. If the answer and comment helped to find this, you might consider accepting the answer so that others that come across this thread will know it the right place to look.